# Select an option to change a page's background color

Tags: javascript

I want to select an option in order to change the background color of a page using JavaScript.

This is what I've tried:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function colorFunction()
        {
        document.bgcolor="this.option[this.selectedIndex]";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="bgcolor form">try it now: 
        <select onchanage="colorFunction">

            <option value="choose">Set Background color
            <option value="FFOOOO">Dark Red
            <option value="OOFFOO">Dark Green
            <option value="OOOOFF">Dark Blue
            <option value="OOOOOO">Black
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

However, my code doesn't work (and I don't know what the errors are).

Comment: `onchanage`? There's no "chanage" event that I know of.

Comment: Please take a few minutes to learn how to pull up the JavaScript console in the browser of your choice. That way you will be able to tell us what errors are occurring and what you don't understand about them. Thanks!

Comment: Simply use onchange  event to do it.

Comment: You can do it also by using jquery.

Comment: Here onchanage spelling is wrong and you have missed few things here
document.bgcolor="this.option[this.selectedIndex]";
Check it,below i have posted an answer what you want

Answer (score 1):

Simply do it by using jquery.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#dropdown").change(function() {
                    var color = $("#dropdown").val();
                    //  alert(color);
                    $("body").css("background-color", color); 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="bgcolor form">try it now: 
            <select id="dropdown">
            <option value="#fff">Set Background color
                <option value="#ff0000">Dark Red
                <option value="#006600">Dark Green
                <option value="#0000ff">Dark Blue
                <option value="#000000">Black
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#dropdown").change(function() {
                    var color = $("#dropdown").val();
                    //  alert(color);
                    $("body").css("background-color", color); 
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="bgcolor form">try it now: 
            <select id="dropdown">
            <option value="#fff">Set Background color
                <option value="#ff0000">Dark Red
                <option value="#006600">Dark Green
                <option value="#0000ff">Dark Blue
                <option value="#000000">Black
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think,this is what you want.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function colorFunction(color)
        {
             
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="bgcolor form">try it now: 
        <select onchange="colorFunction(this.value)">

            <option value="#fff">Set Background color
            <option value="#ff0000">Dark Red
            <option value="#006600">Dark Green
            <option value="#0000ff">Dark Blue
            <option value="#000000">Black
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here i have modified your code  ,please check it.
I have done it in the way you want to get result.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            function colorFunction()
            {
                var color = document.getElementById("thedropdown");
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = color.options[color.selectedIndex].value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="bgcolor form">try it now: 
            <select id="thedropdown" onchange="colorFunction()">

                <option value="#fff">Set Background color
                <option value="#ff0000">Dark Red
                <option value="#006600">Dark Green
                <option value="#0000ff">Dark Blue
                <option value="#000000">Black
            </select>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You have a typo.
It should be:

```
<select onchange="colorFunction">
```

Here's my solution:

```js
function colorFunction(e) {
 if(e.selectedIndex!=0) {
     document.bgColor = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value
   }
}
```

```html
<form name="bgcolor form">Try it now: 
    <select onChange="colorFunction(this)">
        <option value="choose">set background color    
        <option value="FFFFCC">light yellow
        <option value="CCFFFF">light blue
        <option value="CCFFCC">light green
        <option value="CCCCCC">gray
        <option value="FFFFFF">white
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: if suppose i want to show the default color (white) whenever the option is set background color what should i do ? i mean suppose i choose light green color then background color now change to light green then if i choose the set background color option then i want to show the default color (white) of browser. @Forin